# Css calc() function, operator +

Tags: css, less, calc, css-calc

I wanted to do something in CSS with the calc() function but I have a problem.
I try to do this operation and have an error in console :

```
width: calc(~"33.33333333%" + unit(20, px));
```

Console show this message :

> ParseError: Unrecognised input in
>   C:path\translation.less
>   on line 24, column 3:
>
> 23
>
> 24 .title {
>
> 25
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Yet if I do this, I have no error :

```
width: calc(~"66.66666667%" - unit(20, px));
```

Someone would be able to help me and make me understand why this error by changing the operator?

Thank you

Comment: In first snippet the error is thrown because you're trying to add number to a string. The second snippet is compiled fine just because there the `-` can be evaluated as CSS identifier instead of arithmetic  minus (hence the whole expression in parens resolves to `(string identifier number)` statement which is OK, unlike `(string arithm-op number)`.

Comment: It is a little easier described in this way, thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I solve it with trying this :

```
~"calc(33.33333333% + 20px)";
```

And it's perfect working.

Comment: Alternatively it could be just `calc(100%/3 ~"+" 20px);`